# Making copy of GeoServer layer?

Tags: geoserver

In GeoServer, assume I have a layer named "myLayer".

Using GeoServer's REST API, I want to make a complete copy of the layer, let's say "myLayer2" in the same workspace.

What would be my best approach?

*I am on GeoServer 2.9.0, the workspace is a Shape-Directory (although I am looking for a generic solution). I also have the Importer Extension available.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no copy facility in the UI, but I believe you could create one using the REST API and a bit of programming instead, just grab both the resource (feature type or coverage) and the layer using a GET request, and then POST a modified version with only the name changed back:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/index.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to "grab the resource and the layer"? Do i need to download the layers features via WFS, or can it be done even simpler? I want to have a real copy of the layer, so that when the features geometries get updated through WFS-T, the new layer is not affected. Thx!

Comment: I issued a get request to the feature type, took the json response with the feature type's definition, changed the name of the feature type in the json and posted back. That way, I could republish the layer. Nice, but not exactly what I intended. 

Next time, I also changed the `Native_Name` and posted back. That gave me a complete new resource (it even created the shape file in the background) with the feature type's defintion. Not bad. Now, how can I transfer the features from one Layer to the empty layer? Maybe WFS-T? Is that the best option?

Comment: It's the only one I can think of, but WFS-T is not designed for mass data transfers, it's going to be pretty slow... if I had to do it, I'd have a look at the importer extension, and modify/improve it so that the source of an import can be an existing layer.

Comment: Would love to contribute, but I am not a Java programmer. I am gonna do it with WFS-T for now.

Comment: Got it working now with WFS-T, but as you said, it is way too slow. In my case, a featureType with around 8.000 polygons, for example, took more than 5 minutes (not sure how long exactly because the request timed out). I think I have to come up with a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

I went with a different approach in the end:

1. **Download a complete layer through WFS** with `outputFormat` set to `SHAPE-ZIP`. What you get is a zipped shapefile of that layer.
2. Import that file back into Geoserver via the restful **Importer Extension**.

Although this might feel a bit hacky, it works quite well for me.